# Problems with image convolution

Tags: image

I was given an assignment in which I have to write a function to convolve an image with a Gaussian filter (already calculated). I have done it but there is a slight difference between my output picture and my prof output. As you can see that the difference is at the top of his head (1st image is my output, second is from my prof), looks like I missed something? My output looks better but the server rejects it. Can anyone really point out all differences between 2 images so I can try to fix it.

- [This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlXR1.png)
- [This is my prof's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At3fh.png)
- [This is the original one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml7Vu.jpg)

Comment: can you tell what differences you see? because my code is like a mess now .

Comment: Ar i just use a image comparision tool and found out that the top is wrong, I'm working back on the filter to see where the problem is. my code is like a mess that will hurt your brain to read ..